# Set panel height of SlidingUpPanelLayout programmatically

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I have implemented **SlidingUpPanelLayout** in my app and its working fine. Now I want to set the **Panel height dynamically once my activity has created** right now I am doing it in my xml like this

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="true">

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Main Content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/dragView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/follow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/graphic" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

This works fine, but I want to set in the code on **onCreate**

```
 mLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
 mLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new PanelSlideListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelExpanded(View panel) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onPanelExpanded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelCollapsed(View panel) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onPanelCollapsed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelAnchored(View panel) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onPanelAnchored");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelHidden(View panel) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onPanelHidden");
    }
});
mLayout.setPanelHeight(Utils.getPixels(80, getResources()));
```

But while doing this I get a crash

**04-23 20:09:24.010: E/AndroidRuntime(13344): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getLeft()' on a null object reference**

Since **mSlideableView** is being null in **smoothSlideTo** method of SlidingUpPanelLayout.java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you do not give enough time for layout to inflate itself. Same thing happened to me with the same library and I tried this:

```
final int someWaitInterval = 20;
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mLayout.setPanelHeight(params.height);
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(this, someWaitInterval);
            }
        }};
new Handler().postDelayed(r, someWaitInterval);
```

This way it will call itself until it actually changes the panel height.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
mLayout.setPanelHeight(height/2);
```

Also check out this post: [Setting height programatically in Android SlideUp pannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215363/setting-height-programatically-in-android-slideup-pannel)

Comment: The above code works not in onCreate but in onWindowFocusChange for me is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the height in a onPredrawListener.